# Upgrade Vue 3.1 to 3.2

Tags: vue.js, migration, vuejs3

I have an existing Vue 3.1 application. Since 3.2 came out I thought about upgrading it, but I can't find any documentation on how I should approach this. Maybe it's super simple and everyone knows how to do this... Everything I can find talks about upgrading from 2.x to 3.x or just starting from scratch with 3.2.

How should I go about going from 3.1 to 3.2

Thanks

Comment: Nobody talks about it because it's not a big deal. Changes between major versions are major, and between minor versions are... minor. Almost every reputable project around maintains a changelog. Vue isn't a exception, https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#320-2021-08-09

Comment: OK, but how do I actually do it...?

Comment: if your project was created with vue cli, run `vue upgrade`

Comment: honestly, I'm not that sure if it updates client vue version, I would run `npm update` after that just in case

Comment: `vue upgrade` tells me  `DONE  Seems all plugins are up to date. Good work!`... (doesn't do anything)

Comment: `npm update` changed package.json to version 3.2.12 (latest), but a bunch of stuff seems to break when running `npm run serve`. Will have to track them down. Thanks.

Comment: Same issue. `vue upgrade --all` only updates vue-cli plugins but not core packages.
Npm upgrade can break dependencies. Seems easiest way is to create new project with vue cli. It will use latest packages versions.